# RaiseCanExecuteChanged more convenience

Tags: command

I'd like to RaiseCanExecuteChanged when CanExecute condition got changed.
E.g.:

```
public class ViewModel
{
public viewModel()
{
    Command = new RelayCommand(action,condition);
}

private  bool condition()
{
   return  this.Condition1&&this.Condition2&&this.Condition3;
}

public bool Condition1
{
  get{...}
  set{.... **command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();}**
}
public bool Condition2
{
   get{...}
   set{.... command.**RaiseCanExecuteChanged();}**
}
public bool Condition3
{
  get{...}
  set{.... **command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();}**
}
```

}

That works fine.
But I don't like to write so many RaiseCanExecuteChanged, I want to set these changes automatically.
E.g
   In RelayCommand, create a new method  named RaiseChanged

```
  public void RaiseChanged(XXXXXX  XXX,  params string[] propertyNames)
  {
      // for each property in propertyNames,
     // RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
  }
```

I put ViewModel vm  as the parameters, and use vm.PropertyChanged+=(s,e)=>{}
  But I don't think it's a good way to do this.

Does anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I develop my solution where I can do like that:

C# View Model:

```
public bool CanExecuteMethod(object sender)
      {
      }
public void ButtonExecuteMethod(object sender)
      {
      }

public event Action EventNotifyCanExecuteChanged;

private Action _DelegateNotifyCanExecuteChanged;
public Action DelegateNotifyCanExecuteChanged
     {
         get { return _DelegateNotifyCanExecuteChanged; }
         set { _DelegateNotifyCanExecuteChanged = value; }
     }

public void CanExecuteFlag
        {
   if (EventNotifyCanExecuteChanged != null) { EventNotifyCanExecuteChanged(); }
   if (_DelegateNotifyCanExecuteChanged != null) { _DelegateNotifyCanExecuteChanged();} 
        }
```

XAML:

```
< Button Content="Button Cmd-ExCeCh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,231,0,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
        Command="{mark:BindCommandResource MainWindowViewModel,
        ExecuteMethodName=ButtonExecuteMethod,
        CanExecuteMethodName=CanExecuteMethod,
        EventToInvokeCanExecuteChanged=EventNotifyCanExecuteChanged,
        PropertyActionCanExecuteChanged=DelegateNotifyCanExecuteChanged}"  />
```

I put/share this solution in my open source project MVVM-WPF XAML Mark-up Binding Extensions - http://wpfmvvmbindingext.codeplex.com